# indicator multiload not displaying graphs properly Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, indicator-multiload

[How it Looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZTsq.png)

the indicator does not look good to me
I just install need to set it up

Comment: Are you sure this is Ubuntu 16.04 and not Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?